# M2E not adding Groovy source to .classpath on import existing maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, groovy, m2e

Using Eclipse Indigo to import existing maven project, the resulting workspace project does not include `src/main/groovy` or `src/test/groovy` in the build path. I would also like to have the output dir for the groovy code set to `target/test-classes`.

This is my first question to this excellent group, so I hope I cover all of the bases.

### Environment:

- Eclipse Indigo
- m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse  1.2.0.20120903-1050 org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
- m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin  0.15.0.201207090124 org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper.feature.feature.group  Sonatype, Inc.
- APT M2E Connector    0.0.1.3 de.joe.m2e.apt.feature.feature.group    null
- Groovy-Eclipse Feature   2.5.2.xx-20110929-1800-e37  org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group   Codehaus.org
- Groovy-Eclipse M2E integration   2.7.1.xx-20120921-2000-e37RELEASE   org.codehaus.groovy.m2eclipse.feature.group Codehaus.org
- Tycho Project Configurators  0.6.0.201207302152  org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.feature.feature.group    Sonatype, Inc.

My pom.xml for the project is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org        /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
<groupId>com.jha.yhs</groupId>
<artifactId>fraud.server.parent</artifactId>
<version>201203.8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>ach-wire</artifactId>
  <dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.jha.yhs</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspects</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jha.yhs</groupId>
        <artifactId>database</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>r09</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.5-groovy-1.7</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.155</version>
</dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <plugins>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
      <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </plugin>

  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Now this pom.xml is a child (in a subdirectory) of another pom.xml which contains:

```
<build>

  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>

      <configuration>
        <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <compilerArguments>
          <encoding>windows-1252</encoding>
        </compilerArguments>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-source</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>src/main/groovy</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>

      <execution>
        <id>add-test-source</id>
        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-test-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>src/test/groovy</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>


    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError</argLine>
        <includes>
          <include>**/UnitTests.java</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>integration-test</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>verify</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
      <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>

      <dependencies>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
          <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.7</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>

      <configuration>
        <providerSelection>1.7</providerSelection>
      </configuration>

      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
            <goal>testCompile</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

please note, I can add the groovy source folders using: 
 - the GUI's build path
 - by editing the .classpath file
 - run mvn eclipse:eclipse from the command line and the groovy source dir's get added to .classpath but not the output directories.

However, looking at: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329356/eclipse-helios-maven-m2e-groovy-fail) and [this](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) using build-helper should solve the problem. I have tried putting the build-helper reference into the project pom.xml with no change in behavior. I have also tried using the maven-eclipse plugin to set the additional source folders as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179791/eclipse-maven-groovy-src-test-groovy-directory-gets-removed-after-update-pr) and

We have four of these sub projects that use groovy and I would love to not have to add the groovy folders and output folders for main and test for each of them whenever we pull new code from SVN. **It seems that M2E's import maven project just doesn't work correctly.** Neither does maven->updateProject for that matter. What am I missing from this?

As a work around, it seems that m2e 1.2 does not overwrite the .classpath and .project files like m2e 1.0 liked to do, so I can always manually configure the .classpath and .project files and put them into source control.

Comment: What happens when you push all of the gmaven and build-helper configuration down into the child projects?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Groovy in webapp developing with Maven. But I am using `groovy-eclipse-compiler`. First, I configure Maven compiler plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>${groovy-eclipse-compiler.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Then, I configure source directories:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/groovy</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/test/groovy</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

After that, I am able to use Groovy with Eclipse + m2e (actually, I am using Springsource Tool Suite with Groovy plugin). I have Groovy syntax and autocompletion (far from ideal), also I can use Groovy classes from Java and vice versa.